# login or sign up with facebook using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am setting up login and sign up with facebook but get error and that error is requiring to do business verification steps os meta but I don't have it so can you tell me  way can I do it so that login  and sign up with facebook  using firebase can be used  for online app  . here error :
Feature Unavailable
Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app. Please try again later.

I have tried to add business but I failed as they are straight and i don't have business credentials to use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.